# Odd color of the mesh

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I was creating faces with the given vertices and noticed that some parts of my mesh have lighter color than the rest.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me with an explanation? Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: it could be due to different material assigned to those faces, or inverted normals, at least. If you can't solve, try uploading a test file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then edit the question and paste the link given.

Comment: I'm guessing there's an internal face causing your subsurf to pinch in a strange way. You can find it by going into Edit Mode with Vertex Selection enabled, and Select > Non-Manifold.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @m.ardito and @Mentalist, I was able to remove the odd shading by locating the internal face and removing it by >> Edit Mode with Vertex Selection enabled, and Select > Non-Manifold.

[image]